# How much of a strain on servers is jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I haven't used jQuery yet, but one can't help but notice the plethora of questions that involve it.  In reading about the basics, [some](http://www.jscripters.com/jquery-disadvantages-and-advantages/) mention a "strain on the client computer and maybe your web server as well if you intend to host the JQuery script on your own web server".

I am not so much concerned about client-side, but wonder what kind of strain we would be looking at.  I [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Including_the_library) that the jQuery library "can be included within a web page by linking to a local copy, or to one of the many copies available from public servers".  I wonder why Microsoft (or whoever) would want millions of people using their servers to DL jQuery libraries? Does the client DL the file all at once with each session, or are just the parts needed DL'd and accessed locally when events/effects/functions fire?  How often is the library purged client-side?  If I had, say 100'000 visitors and 1'000'000 hits on my site, how many times would the library file be DL'd? Once per session?  Sorry for posing this n00b question, but I am reading some conflicting things, and wonder if someone could fill me in.

Comment: That post is silly. jQuery is downloaded all-at-once, but it should only be downloaded once per session *at worst*, and it uses less bandwidth than many images do. Unless you're designing a website to use the absolute minimum amount of bandwidth, this shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Depends on how correctly and aggressively you set up caching through HTTP response headers on the server side. Considering that e.g. a specific point release of jQuery will *never* change, I 'd say that the strain is a lot less than you might imagine for those numbers.

Comment: Google finds some reasons: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: Sorry if it seems silly.  I knew the library itself was small, but didn't quite realize how small it actually was. I thought I would ask, given what I read in my first link, and the fact that I couldn't find anything about it.  Now I know there is a reason why it's not mentioned anywhere... if the point is moot :c)

Comment: Use the jQuery that is hosted by Google's free CDN and it will be zero impact on your servers.  In fact, it will require less impact on your servers than your own JS library.  Plus, using Google's CDN will increase the performance of your app because the common CDN version of jQuery is very likely to already be in the browser cache from other web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery framework, as is the case with any other client side script or style sheet, is stored (cached) on the client once downloaded.

The latest version of jQuery is about 31kb when minified for production, so this is in line with any other image or lightweight html page in your application except for the fact that it will be cached on the client and not downloaded twice.

Allowing the jQuery base to be hosted by a CDN like Google is also an option.  [Here is a great blog post about doing that](http://encosia.com/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/).

Comment: I didn't realize it was quite that small.  Are most of the plug-ins similar in size?

Comment: Most plug-ins that extend jQuery are likely to be smaller ;).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Most static content, like jQuery libraries in Javascript files, is not a strain.  You mention 100k visitors, is that per day?  Per month?  Really changes the expectations.

You don't have to host the jQuery files on your servers anyway, you can use Google's Content Delivery Network (CDN) or Microsoft's CDN (like https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) in order to eliminate any issues on your servers whatsoever related to just the downloading of the file.

Comment: That's why I asked, as we have a high level of traffic.  If it's no different in size than an image, then it sounds like it shouldn't be any more of a strain than adding another image to a page.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to mitigate these issues.

1. you would want to make sure that the browser cached which ever javascript libraries you use.  Browsers typically do this, and you can really enforce it with the html5 cache manifest.  That way, each client only loads your code once.
2. Minimize your src.
3. Configure your web servers to keep common static resources (like your src code and images) in memory, and gzip it for transfer to lessen the size of the download.

Also, there is something called **capacity planning**.  If your application is going to get 100k visitors, you need to have the hardware to support that.

Answer (score 1):

The file would be downloaded once per user. Once it's downloaded the first time, the user's browser caches it, and it's never downloaded again. Compare this to your HTML pages, which will be reloaded every single time the user clicks a link.

At 33kb, JQuery is about the same size as a large HTML document, and many times smaller than most images. Since it's just a static file, it introduces basically no server load. According to [this article](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/serving-small-static-files-which-server-to-use/), common server software can handle dozens of thousands of static requests *per second*, which is more most websites ever have to deal with.

That's why Google and Microsoft are okay with hosting jQuery for everybody - it's so small,  it doesn't bother their servers much.

In summary; don't worry about it. jQuery will never cause a problem for your server.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't realize it was quite that small. Are most of the plug-ins also small?

Comment: Yup! The vast majority of them are even smaller, in fact.